# Get the Chat Room List from the Openfire Sever USING Asmack

Tags: java, android, chat, openfire, asmack

Any body know how to get the  chat room list from openfireServer using Asmack library .Help me .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to get list of room names that the user has joined:

```
Iterator roomsJoinedByUser = MultiUserChat.getJoinedRooms(connection, "abc@abc.com");
```

Use this to get list all hosted rooms:

```
Collection<HostedRoom> rooms = MultiUserChat.getHostedRooms(connection, "service_name");
```

Comment: I need all the  all the public chat rooms

Answer (score 1):

here is my code hope it helps

```html
  Collection<HostedRoom> rooms = MultiUserChat.getHostedRooms(connection, "conference.nubes-pc-1");

            if (!rooms.isEmpty()){
                for (HostedRoom room : rooms) {
                    Log.d("yo", room.getName()+" "+ room.getJid());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see,  MultiUserChat.*getHostedRooms* can help you:

```
public static List<HostedRoom>  getHostRooms(XMPPConnection xmppConnection){
    List<HostedRoom> roominfos = new ArrayList<HostedRoom>();
    try {
        new ServiceDiscoveryManager(xmppConnection);
        Collection<HostedRoom> hostrooms = 
MultiUserChat.getHostedRooms(xmppConnection,xmppConnection.getServiceName());
        for (HostedRoom entry : hostrooms) {
            roominfos.add(entry);
            Log.i("room", "name：" + entry.getName() + " - ID:" + entry.getJid());
        }
        Log.i("room", "number:" + roominfos.size());
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        Log.e("getHostRooms",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return roominfos;
}
```